# Git Extensions: Unable to push to repo after renaming it (gitolite)

Tags: git, gitolite, git-extensions

I logged into my server as an administrator (not as the Git user, which may have been a mistake), and did:

`mv oldrepo.git newrepo.git`

Then, I edited gitolite.conf, from...

```
repo oldrepo
    RW+     =   id_rsa
```

... to...

```
repo newrepo
    RW+     =   id_rsa
```

... and pushed that to the gitolite-admin repo.

Now, when I attempt to push to newrepo, I get the following error (using Git Extensions):

---

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

FATAL: W any newrepo id_rsa DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Done

---

I'm still able to push to all of my other repositories just fine, no problems.

What have I done?

Comment: just fyi, this part of the message you show: "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." is not from gitolite; clearly there is/was an OS permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you moving the repo is *probably* the issue. I would hop back on the server and check the owner of `newrepo.git` with `ls -l`.

If `newrepo.git` and/or the files it contains are owned by root (or your admin account), you can run this as root (or with sudo)

```
chown -R git newrepo.git
```

Afterwards, `ls -l` should show that it is owned by git, not root.

If that's not the issue, I would double check your remotes on the local computer with `git remote -v` and also make sure there's nothing weird in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: They're all owned by git.

Screw it, I'm just going to completely reinstall gitolite, and remake all of my repos (to which I am no longer able to push, having followed the advice of someone else, elsewhere on the Internet).  It'll be faster and less painful than trying to work through Git's idiosyncrasies and cryptic UNIX command lines and files *again*.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the [move/rename process with Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#removingrenaming-a-repo):

> Renaming a repo is also not automatic. Here's what you do (and the order is important):
>
> 1. Go to the server and rename the repo at the Unix command line.
>      Don't forget to retain the "`.git`" extension on the directory name.
> 2. Change the name in the `conf/gitolite.conf` file in your gitolite-admin repo clone, and add/commit/push.

The [OP MiloDC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288102/milodc) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544922/git-extensions-unable-to-push-to-repo-after-renaming-it-gitolite/31547676#comment51106037_31547676):

> I've got it working now (by reinstalling Gitolite and going through the set-up procedures again), I suspect that logging in as an admin and effecting the rename caused problems.

Comment: Did you read my question thoroughly?  This is precisely what I did.

Comment: @MiloDC I agree, the only difference is the account you used for the operation.

Comment: Yeah, although I've got it working now (by reinstalling Gitolite and going through the set-up procedures again), I suspect that logging in as an admin and effecting the rename caused problems.